# C++ Boost::Asio I got the remote.Endpoint().address, now how to I resolve to Hostname?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm using Boost::Asio.

I have a server, and on connections I can print out the clients IP. 
However, I want to get and print out their resolved hostname also.

```
asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
// Do all your accepting and other stuff here.

std::string s = socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
```

s prints 127.0.0.1  fine,  but now I want the resolved hostname of the IP.
In basic sockets you use:

```
gethostbyaddr((char *)&from.sin_addr, sizeof (struct in_addr),from.sin_family);
```

I've tried using the:

```
//tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v6(), host, port);
tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), host, port);
tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
```

But haven't had much luck or ability to find any concrete examples this for resolved connections after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [async_resolve](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/async_resolve/overload2.html). It shouldn't be much different from other async operations in Asio.

A simple example:

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;
using namespace std;

void resolve_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec,
                     tcp::resolver::iterator it)
{
  tcp::resolver::iterator end;
  for (; it != end; ++it) {
    cout << it->host_name() << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  io_service ioservice;
  tcp::resolver resolv{ioservice};
  tcp::endpoint endpoint{address::from_string("74.125.239.48"), 80};
  resolv.async_resolve(endpoint, resolve_handler);
  ioservice.run();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got a mock up working, although it doesn't seem to grab hostnames on 192. internal addresses :(